# Spring creates two of @Configuration beans starting up

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I have following class:

```
@Configuration
public class EndpointStatus {

private static final Logger serverLogger = LogManager.getLogger(EndpointStatus.class);

private Long id;
private volatile Status status;

@OneToOne
private volatile CurrentJob currentJob;

public enum Status {
    AVAILABLE,
    BUSY
}

@Bean
@Primary
public EndpointStatus getEndpointStatus() {
    serverLogger.info("STATUS CREATED");
    return new EndpointStatus();
}

public EndpointStatus() {
}

public CurrentJob getCurrentJob() {
    return currentJob;
}

public void setCurrentJob(CurrentJob currentJob) {
    this.currentJob = currentJob;
}

public Status getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public boolean isBusy() {
    return getStatus() == Status.BUSY;
}
```

Bean is used in endpoint which is annotated with @Component

and then i try to get the bean in endpoint like

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(EndpointStatus.class);
EndpointStatus sc = ctx.getBean(EndpointStatus.class);
```

`EndpointStatus` is not used anywhere else.

To my knowledge, there should be no reason to create a second bean...

However at startup I always get

```
INFO 6169 [main] c.e.k.d.r.m.i.EndpointStatus             : STATUS CREATED
INFO 6169 [main] c.e.k.d.r.m.i.EndpointStatus             : STATUS CREATED
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

Have tried every answer given to no avail whatsoever..

my class now looks like this

```
@Configuration
public class EndpointStatusConfig {

private static final Logger serverLogger = LogManager.getLogger(JavaXRest.class);

private Long id;
private volatile Status status = EndpointStatusConfig.Status.AVAILABLE;

@OneToOne
private volatile CurrentJob currentJob;

public enum Status {
    AVAILABLE,
    BUSY
}

@Bean
@Primary
public EndpointStatusConfig getEndpointStatus() {
    serverLogger.info("STATUS CREATED");
    return new EndpointStatusConfig();
}

public CurrentJob getCurrentJob() {
    return currentJob;
}

public void setCurrentJob(CurrentJob currentJob) {
    this.currentJob = currentJob;
}

public Status getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public boolean isBusy() {
    return getStatus() == Status.BUSY;
}

  }
```

no matter @Component or @Configuration, making call to sc in endpoint will result in hundreds of beans created crashing the app...

**EDIT2:
this is just getting worse and worse**... 
now even call to

```
if ( sc.isBusy() ) { return Response.ok( sc.getCurrentJob() ).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build(); }
```

will jump to @Bean and create as many EndpointStatus objects as it can before the application crashes.... @Component creates one at startup, then thousands. @Configuration will create 2 at startup and then thousands also...

Comment: Your bean should be an `@Component` and should be injected you should NOT create an application context to get bean as that will recreate a new instance again .

Comment: Problem is as well that you are declaring the same class as `@Configuration` and again as `@Bean`. Creating 2 instances of the same bean.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guesswork but defining the configuration class both as a configuration and a factory bean return type is probably the issue.
`EndpointStatus` is a configuration class as the class is declared with `@Configuration` and a configuration class produces a bean in Spring and it is also an explicit bean as you annotated the bean factory method `getEndpointStatus()` with `@Bean`.
It is a little like if you had defined twice the bean.

Comment: So, i dont need AtConfiguration and AtBean at the same class? has this changed or am i missunderstanding? https://www.journaldev.com/21033/spring-configuration-annotation, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm granted, these are kinda old, but both cleary show using both annotations in same class

Comment: Generally you don't want to do that.  1)  Are you sure ? I don't see this in the page. 2)Whatever https://www.journaldev.com is not necessary the best reference for coding.  Configuration is designed to declare some beans not to declare itself as a bean. It makes no sense. If you want that the class be a bean, you should favor `@Component` on the class itself.

Comment: Okey sure, i'll use @Component then, but still spring tells me there is more than one bean created. with Component, Bean and no contructor i still get atleast two beans

Comment: The sample you point to is having a separate configuration class (the `HelloWorldConfig` ) and bean (the `HelloWorld` class). You are reusing the same class to be both. Don't do things like that.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change the name of your Configuration class from EndpointStatus to EndpointStatusConfig and this will then only create a single bean with EndpointStatus class.

As you are annotating EndpointStatus both as @Configuration & @Bean it creates 2 Beans.

Comment: are you saying that Configuration class needs to be named "Config" ? I start to feel that using Spring is more about knowing these random gotchas than knowing java... i'll try it

Comment: No, I am not saying you need Config in name but the name of bean and configuration file should be different.

Comment: This happends because Spring use reflexion to add beans to the context

Comment: Will try this when i get back! thanks for suggestion

Comment: I dont understand... the bean is still created twice as soon as i try to call it in endpoint with EndpointStatusConfig sc = ctx.getBean(EndpointStatusConfig.class); there is again two beans created

Comment: with Autowire, it is created just once in startup.. is there any understandable guide i can read to understand this clusterfuck of beans?

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is using `@Configuration` instead of `@Component`

The `@Configuration` will try add to spring context any `@Autowired` or `@Bean` inside the class with `@Configuration` but won't add it self to the spring context.

If you want to add that class as a bean to the spring context you should use `@Component`

Edit:

Did you try to inject EndpointStatus class with the `@Configuration` on it self?

In case you don't and don't know what is injection in spring try this:

```
@Autowired
EndpointStatus status;

void yourMethod(){
   //Change this 
   //ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(EndpointStatus.class);
   //EndpointStatus sc = ctx.getBean(EndpointStatus.class);
   //Use instead the status variable declared before
}
```

Comment: changed annotation to @Component, application now creates hundreds of Status beans at startup until it crashes

Comment: I didn't notice that you have bean and configuration clas with the same name, you problem is solved by Jaspreet Jolly